# Is it possible to have a TextView without a system Keyboard but what i write by myself?

Tags: iphone, keyboard

I just want to use my own keyboard and input method when type word in a TextView in my own apps without jailbreak my iPhone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your own view and set it as the `inputView` property of the text view. You'll need to write your own event handling code to update the text after each key press.

I have heard anecdotally on this site that Apple aren't too keen on keyboard replacements if your keyboard is still basically a keyboard (ie just qwerty buttons, but different shapes or looks) but if you have genuine different functionality in there you shouldn't have a problem.